# Multiple elements with same id get name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have mulitple elements

```
<a href='#' id='Favorites[]' name='Favorites1'>1</a>
<a href='#' id='Favorites[]' name='Favorites2'>2</a>
<a href='#' id='Favorites[]' name='Favorites..'>..</a>
<a href='#' id='Favorites[]' name='Favorites1000'>1000</a>
```

[I trying to get name of clicked element](http://fiddle.jshell.net/bnujr02o/2/)

```
$("#Favorites").on('click', function() {
    alert(this.name);
});
```

But it works only for first element, others elements not react on click event

How to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`id` should be unique, so you need to use `class` instead, otherwise it will only select the first dom element with the `id`

```js
$(".Favorites").on('click', function() {
  alert(this.name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#' class='Favorites' name='Favorites1'>1</a>
<a href='#' class='Favorites' name='Favorites2'>2</a>
<a href='#' class='Favorites' name='Favorites..'>3</a>
<a href='#' class='Favorites' name='Favorites1000'>4</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that the jquery selector #Favourites is only intended to find a single 'id' with that value so the others are ignored.

You could consider converting the 'Favourites' to being a class like:

```
<a href='#' class='Favorites' name='Favorites1'>1</a>
<a href='#' class='Favorites' name='Favorites2'>2</a>
<a href='#' class='Favorites' name='Favorites..'>..</a>
<a href='#' class='Favorites' name='Favorites1000'>1000</a>
```

then use

```
$('.Favorites').on('click', function() {
    alert(this.name);
});
```

I'm pretty sure you should only have one 'id' attribute per dom with a specific value typically. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp [w3schools id attribute documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp)